# ASP.NET GridView sorting on method data

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sorting, templatefield, spgridview

I'm binding a GridView to a domain model object, this domain model object has a method for working out a formatted value to display on the grid.  I'd like to use this method for my display value, which is fine, but I'd also like to be able to sort on the value returned by that method.  My sort expression can only take in a property/field at the moment.

Help please!  What do I need to do to get this to work?

I'm using an SPGridView actually, but that doesn't make a lot of difference to my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: It would help to know the signature of the method.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly then I can just think aloud - 
You can always get your data into a datatable and sort it according to your needs before you bind it again to your gridview.

Since I have never worked with SharePoint web controls, so am unsure. Thats why posted it as a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The databinding can only occur against properties (not methods), so you could make a property that calls your custom display method and returns its output.

Comment: That does not overcome the problem really, it just works around it.  I have domain model objects that I'd like to bind to the grid view, so adding UI-specific properties (even though they'd call methods) is my big no no - otherwise I could have just added the property and put the method's logic in there!

Comment: I should have added that my methods are "extention methods" that I have added at the UI, so they are not UI-specific core methods inside my domain objects :)

Comment: In that case, you should set up your grid manually rather than databinding.  That way you will have full control over how the cells are populated.  You will have to implement your own sorting too though.